# Validating 100k records with database table entries

Tags: database, excel, hibernate

I have an excel with 100,000 entries, I need to validate each record with database and validate whether same record exists in database (DB2).
What is the optimised way of doing this comparison and validation?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not easy.  You may convert the excel sheet into a db database and using some scripts/programs you have to validate them.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution by @Jim Garrison. If you can't solve your issue that way, I would suggest creating a stored procedure and passing your data(only needed columns e.g. id) in chunks (as you have limitation in passing params to DB) to that procedure and getting the non-existing ones as result.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the suggestion.